# "introspect" expected amount of returns within function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-calls

Hello people,
I'm currently working on a python module providing tools for co-workers to use and some of the functions I'm trying to provide can return quite a bit of useful information (say, 5 return values), but in most use case, only the first two will be needed.

I know python is great for writing highly dynamic programs especially since we can ask for informations about currently running system, so I though of searching a little, but I couldn't seem to find. (I found a lot of interesting discussion, but nothing actually discussing my issue.)

**Is there a way, from within a function, to know the amount of expected return values ?**

For instance, there could be the function:

```
def lazyOdd():
    return 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21
```

Which would be called using `one, three, five = lazyOdd()`.

*Edit*: Apparently it wasn't clear at all, what I seek looks like :

```
def lazyReturn():
    return (val1, val2) if expectedReturns == 2 else (val1, val2, val3, val4)
```

I know that in this case, it definitely isn't the best way to proceed and almost any kind of iterable could do, but with values that aren't linked at all, it wouldn't be as simple. If possible, since most use case are going to be using only two results, I would like to avoid returning a big tuple, for many co-workers won't even know the function return the others values and it'll be quite error-prone.

Can I do that ?

*Edit:* Also, I don't mind if the solution includes some overhead, as I will most likely win a lot of time by not processing the last three values.

*Edit²*: Maybe the best way really is to pass another parameter specifying the amount of values expected ?

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself. _"I would like to avoid returning a big tuple"_. Try out `type(lazyOdd())`.

Comment: <"class 'tuple'> ? I don't get what you meant here. ><

Comment: @Alceste_ his point is that no matter how you deal with it, you're returning "one big tuple" either way. Whether you explicitly create the tuple (i.e.  `tuple = (a,b,c)` and return that or just say  `return a,b,c` makes no difference, in both cases you end up with the exact same tuple.

Comment: Sorry for being cryptic: Just that it already returns a `tuple`. You should be able to see the amount of return values by `len(lazyOdd())`.

Comment: I know it does, my question was about allowing it to return smaller tuple, I'll edit it so it gets clearer.

Comment: I don't know it that really helps that much, but there is always the way to have an optional argument which tells you how many of the return values you want to return. you could do `lazyF(args,ret=2): .... return result[ret]` or similar things... I am not aware of a way to infer the number of variables the return value should be bound to

Comment: @pingul: I believe OP wants to examine the call stack and return only as many values as the function call expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Caching

It's hard to tell from your description, but it seems that you need [caching](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/function_caching.html).

This way, you can write multiple functions. One is used for heavy calculations, the others output the correct format and number of values. If the heavy calculation is called a second time with the same input value, the previous result is returned.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def heavy_common_calculation(x):
    print("HEAVY CALCULATION FOR %d. Should only be done once!" % x)
    result = x**2
    return result

def get_two_values(x):
    return x, heavy_common_calculation(x)

def get_four_values(x):
    y = heavy_common_calculation(x)
    return x, y, y**2, y**3

print(get_two_values(3))
# HEAVY CALCULATION FOR 3. Should only be done once!
# (3, 9)
print(get_four_values(3))
# (3, 9, 81, 729)
```

## Generator

Do you want to implement a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)?

```
def lazyOdd():
    x = 1
    while True:
        yield x
        x = x + 2

odd_gen = lazyOdd()
print(next(odd_gen))
# 1
print(next(odd_gen))
# 3
print(next(odd_gen))
# 5
print(next(odd_gen))
# 7
```

If you want a value, it gets calculated. If you don't need it, nothing happens and nothing is calculated in vain.

`len(odd_gen)` isn't defined because it would start an infinite loop.

## Keyword argument

You could use an argument to tell the function how many results you need:

```
def f(x, detail='low'):
    a, b = x, x**2
    if detail == 'high':
        return a, b, 'something', 'else'
    else:
        return a, b


print(f(3))
# (3, 9)
print(f(3, detail='high'))
# (3, 9, 'something', 'else')
```

Comment: The example is simplified as I'm not allowed to publicate my work, but as explained right under it, I could need to return values that aren't linked at all.

Comment: @Alceste_ If the values aren't linked, maybe you should consider writing two different functions?

Comment: ><
Well, they ARE linked, but only by the fact that they both need the same extra-large calculation to be done to determine them. The other half of return values need another chunk of processing that is different from the first half.

Comment: @Alceste_: Then it sounds like you need caching. See update

Comment: Yeah that seems great, sadly enough I need to respect the current structure and can't have multiple functions for this task. 

But I take it the answer to the question (the one in bold) is that it can't be achieved, and I'll need the default value argument. Since you also gave that one, I'll probably accept your answer. 

- Though I'll wait a little in case someone ends up coming and giving something clear answering the question directly (so many xy in my post, I guess I really am lacking clarity).

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite get what you want to do. The amount of elements in a tuple that is returnded by a function is decided by the function or more specifically by the programmmer who wrote the function. If you coworkers are only interested in the first two elements they could do this:

```
one, three, *_ = lazyOdd()
```

_ is a garbage variable that stores the rest of the tuple.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that to keep all of the unwanted returns in a single variable, definitely interesting and might prove useful, but not exactly as convenient as getting the amount of expected returns from within the called function, as it could prevent it from doing extra calculation.